# Unexpected error while getting the method or property insert on object Apiary.dfareporting.ads

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet, double-click-advertising

I try to call this API with the following `ad` object.

```
  var ad = DoubleClickCampaigns.Ads.insert(
    {
      
      "campaignId": parseInt(singlePlacementArray[0]),
      "advertiserId": parseInt(inputSheet.getRange("J9").getValue()),
      
      //"accountId": inputSheet.getRange("H9").getValue(),
      "name": singlePlacementArray[1],
       "active": true,
       "archived": false,
      "type": "AD_SERVING_TRACKING",
      "startDate": Utilities.formatDate(singlePlacementArray[5], ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
      "endDate": Utilities.formatDate(singlePlacementArray[6], ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
      "placementAssignments": [
        {
          "placementId": parseInt(singlePlacementArray[9]),
          "active": true,
          //"sslRequired": false,
        }
      ]
    }, "6485800");
```

I get this vague error:

`Unexpected error while getting the method or property insert on object Apiary.dfareporting.ads.`

What might be wrong with the `ad` object?

Is it about the `dates`, the `type`?

Comment: When I saw your current script in your question, I noticed that in your object, `startDate` and `endDate` are used. In this case, when those are changed to `startTime` and `endTime`, respectively, what result will you obtain? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-advertisers/rest/v3.4/ads#Ad) In that case, the format might be required to be changed from `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Thank, but the document says it's required without telling the format: `startTime 
string

Date and time that this ad should start serving. If creating an ad, this field must be a time in the future. This is a required field on insertion.`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I might not be able to understand about your replying, in your question, `startDate` and `endDate` are used. But in your actual situation, `startTime` and `endTime` have already been used. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The user inputs them in the spreadsheet, and I use this to fill in the ad object sent to the API. Do you think the enum "type" should be sent as a string? any working example I can find and compare to?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could find it, I would like to tell you. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.